# Why does my DensityPlot colour gradient radically change if I extend the x axis beyond a certain point?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I've solved a modified 1D diffusion equation in order to model the moving boundary of an evaporating liquid. I used NDSolve (with {t, 0, 1}) and have tried to plot the evolution over time as a density plot, with density representing vapour phase concentration.

This works well as long as I limit the time axis ('x' axis) to a certain point. If I extend it any further the density plot colours change (a) inside the liquid, where the concentration should remain at 1 and (b) on the left hand side of the diagram, near the initial condition, which is that concentration is 0 everywhere above the liquid. At both of these places it goes from having some colour value to just being completely white.

The scale legend also changes - in the first case it runs from 0 to 1 (as expected) and in the second case it runs from just 0.3 to 1.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

The two images are below

[image: correct density plot, t-axis ends at t=0.81. Liquid is below red dashed line, vapour is above]
[image: incorrect density plot, t-axis ends at t=0.82. Note]

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing and being able to experiment with your code; however, try changing the `PlotRange` option to either `PlotRange->All` or `PlotRange->Full`. What effect does that have?

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for your help, this seems to work! I still don't understand why - there's nothing in the code to suggest `t ~ 0.82` is special in any way. But setting `PlotRange->All` fills in the empty space as I was expecting.

Comment: With `PlotRange->Automatic`, plot functions select a `PlotRange` that shows a "likely" range of interest. If that is not your range of interest, you need to specify a different range.